# Aligning vertices

Tags: modeling

In the image I want to make the middle vertices out of all the selected vertices align with the 2 other vertices selected. So pretty much I want to know how to make the bottom image look like the top image [image]

[image]

Comment: you can copy the values for Z and Y of one of the other 2 vertices to the one in the middle

Comment: Aside from already added solutions you have many other ways, like changing Pivot Point to *Active*, selecting vertices to align and lastly - vertex to align to and scale to 0 by Z axis (in this case), or just flatten the edge / face by Z axis.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to do that is to turn on vertex snapping.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: That will work only if the first and last vertices are aligned with world coordinates.

Answer (score 2):

Simple way to do that is with looptools addon, which can be enabled in the user preferences.

Once its enabled, select the vertices you want to align and in tools panel, Looptools section, select **Gstretch**, that will make an even distribution of  connected vertices between the first and last one in that selection.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Another way, not stated above, to do this is:

1. Select the vertice that is the desired height already
2. Press **N** to toggle the properties panel.
3. Copy the Z coordinate
4. Select the vertice that you want to re-align
5. In the properties panel, paste the z coordinate